# How to update SP List Default view using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, list-view, api

I am looking to update my list default view (All Items) using REST API, what i am looking exactly is to show/hide columns.

When i checked the result of this request:

```
https://m365x873105.sharepoint.com/sites/<Site Name>/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<List Name>')/views
```

It appears that there is a certain fields that should be edited in order to update the View, the field are colored in the picture below:

[image]

Now i should implement a POST request with the proper Headers in order to update the view, that's my try which is not working:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What am I missing here ! please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question

there is some endpoints which are useful to edit, i get to manage my issue by removing all the fields with one request, then add every single field i want it to appear in the default view one by one. please go refer to the following links:

[Remove All fields](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246804(v%3Doffice.15))

[Add field](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246043(v=office.15))

[Move field to](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245480(v=office.15))

Fortunately i found these endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

get your view : /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/Views/getByTitle('test')

and set it to default view

`function UpdateList(){
    var listName="Pages";
    var list = {
        "__metadata": { "type": 'SP.View'  },
        "DefaultView": true
    };`

```
jq.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/Views/getByTitle('test')",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(list),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": jq("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
        "If-Match": "*"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success');
        window.location.href=window.location.href;
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.dir(data);
    }
});
```

}
UpdateList();

Comment: Hello Frederic, this will only set the selected view as default, doesn't it ?

Comment: Hello Aimen, yes, it's ok on my SP2016

Comment: That's not what i am looking for, i said i want to update this default view by showing and hiding columns